# Xamarin 64 bit convertion

Tags: c#, iphone, xamarin.ios, xamarin, ios8

I have a number of older apps I want to publish to iPhone 6, but it appears I need to add 64 bit features?

How do I migrate an app so that I can choose i386 + x86_64 in the Advanced Build options?

Right now only x386 appears as a choice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can publish 32 bits only application for iOS, including the iPhone 6 (and 6 Plus). IOW right now 64 bits (or 32/64 FAT applications) are **not** required to publish to the Apple AppStore.

There's no doubt 64 bits is the future and we can *guess* that Apple will make such binaries required in the future.

The latest versions of Xamarin.iOS (since 7.4) includes a **preview** of our [unified API](http://blog.xamarin.com/unified-api-with-64-bit-support-for-ios-and-mac/) which lets you build, from the same source, both a 32bits and a 64bits applications. If you're building such a **unified** application then you should have the option (in either XS or VS) to get it working for both i386 and x86_64.

Note that the 64bits support simulator is not very useful, what you really want is the ARMv7 + ARM64 for devices (but the same instructions, as above, applies as well).

Comment: Hmm. Why does the Xamarin IDE indicate this when trying to debug to iPhone 6 Simulator: error MT0036: Cannot launch a 64 bits simulator for a 32 bits app. Please enable the correct architecture(s) in your project's iOS Build options (Advanced page).

Comment: The latest XS and XI 8.0 builds won't report this error (the new simulator targets are a very new). They should be available very soon (if not already).

Comment: You are correct, I just checked the Xamarin update and there is a new 8.0.0.60. Downloading now. Xamarin support is super awesome.

Comment: So just to support 32bit and 64bit in the same binary as Apple wants, we have to migrate existing Xamarin iOS app from Monotouch to Unified Apis involving major code changes! Is that the right understanding?

Thanks.

Comment: Moving from *classic* to *unified* is generally a fairly easy update. Xamarin Studio (5.7) has a tool that automates most of the process. Most of the rest consist of validating any 32bits assumptions (which is also a requirement for ObjC apps).